# Doubt of a problem of a tagged partition

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

The problem is: Let $\dot{P}$ be a tagged partition on $[0,3]$. Show that the union $U_{1}$ of all subintervals in $\dot{P}$ with tags in $[0,1]$ satisfies $[0,1-\Vert{\dot{P}}\Vert]\subseteq U_{1} \subseteq [0,1+\Vert{\dot{P}}\Vert]$.

My question is the next: If I take the partition $P=(0,0.5,0.7,3)$ and tags $t_{1}=0.3,t_{2}=0.6,t_{3}=0.8$, then $\Vert{\dot{P}}\Vert=2.3$. ¿What happend with $[0,1-\Vert{\dot{P}}\Vert]\subseteq U_{1}$? I´ll have $[0,1-2.3]\subseteq U_{1}$ and it doesn't have sense.

This problem is from the book "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Robert Bartle. (Section 7.1, exercise 4(a))

Comment: What do you mean by $\|\dot P\|$ ?

Comment: The partition norm $\|P\|$ is the maximum length of partition subintervals.

Comment: $\Vert \dot{P} \Vert$ means the norm of the tagged partition $\dot{P}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $[0,1-2.3] = [0,-1.3] = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}\, | \, x \geqslant 0 \,\text{and}\, x \leqslant -1.3\} = \emptyset \subseteq U_1$, since the empty set is a subset of any set.  It is true vacuously that every element of the empty set belongs to $U_1$ since there are no elements.